# I am trying to download an image from a link and display it in an image view, but the line imgView.setImageBitmap(myImg); is throwing some error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get an image from the internet through a link and display it on an imageView with the press of a button but the image won't display. After some debugging I found out that the line 
    imgView.setImageBitmap(myImg);
is throwing an exception.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imgView;

public void imageFromWeb(View view){

    imageDownloader task = new imageDownloader();
    Bitmap myImg;
    try{
        myImg = task.execute("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/R_federer.jpg").get();
        imgView.setImageBitmap(myImg);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("check","error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public class imageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return img;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    imgView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

When I run the app and click the button I see that the "check error" line is printed which I log.i in the catch block of imageFromWeb function, along with

```
2019-05-28 10:29:13.515 4764-4764/com.ashwin.imagefromweb I/Choreographer: Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

What is going wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should remove the get() and set image in onPostExecute

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried doing that but the imgView.setImageBitmap() line is still throwing an error!

Comment: Unless you're really set at using AsyncTask for this, why not try Picasso or Glide, which handles all these things nicely in the background.

Comment: @AshwinBhatnagar post what you tried

Answer (score 1):

Try using Glide for accessing images from url

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load("url here") // image url
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) // any placeholder to load at start
        .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)  // any image in case of error
        .override(200, 200); // resizing
        .centerCrop();     
        .into(imageView);  // imageview object
```